# Initialize document data source by key attribute (instead of UNID)

Tags: xpages

We have documents containing "key" of some referenced document. There is reason we don't use UNIDs. I want to initialize data source by this key value. So in Document ID property I write script to open view, look up specified document and use looked up UNID to initialize data source.
I think this is not optimal solution.

Question: is there a better way to initialize document data source based on key value?

Sample code:

```
@DbLookup("", "view", "key", 1, '[RETURNDOCUMENTUNIQUEID]');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the document's UNID by key in a view is probably indeed the best way to do it. However, you could speed up repeated calls a bit by writing a managed bean to act as a cache. If, for example, you wrote a Java class that implements java.util.Map, stub out most of the methods, and implement a .get(...) method that takes the key as a parameter, you could reference it like (assuming you call the bean "DocKeyManager"):

<xp:dominoDocument ... documentId="${DocKeyManager[someKey]}"/>

That way, you could cache the value from the .get(...) call and not have to hit the database each time, and it'd also let you change the lookup algorithm later.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Tims article about converting strings to MD2. 
this way I think you can convert your string id's to a unid and access them using getDocumentByUnid

http://xmage.gbs.com/blog.nsf/SearchResults?OpenNavigator&Query=md2

Comment: very interesting read, but it would need to alter documents' UNIDs to explicit value = MD2(key) - and that means we could store UNID instead of key. further more: reason for not using UNID references is the fact it can be changed under some circumstances (resolved conflict, copy/paste) and even MD2 approach can lead to lost of data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

We do this a lot, but just remember to do the lookup once (on page load via the $ tag) instead of dynamic (# tag).

If you do it dynamic it will end up doing multiple lookups . . .

The suggestion from Jesse Gallagher to cache lookup results is also a good idea.